# CoreText FindColorBitmapForGlyph crash on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-text, ios12

Some users of ours are experiencing a really bizarre crash with the following stack trace. This happens when the user launches the app. The devices with this crash are – weirdly – all iPhone 7 phones running iOS 12. My Google-fu is completely failing me. Has anyone else experienced this and have a way to correct? Thank you!

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreText                       0x211894400 TFont::FindColorBitmapForGlyph(double, unsigned short, TsbixContext const&, unsigned long&, unsigned long&, unsigned char&, double&, double&) const + 280
1  CoreText                       0x211894340 TFont::FindColorBitmapForGlyph(double, unsigned short, TsbixContext const&, unsigned long&, unsigned long&, unsigned char&, double&, double&) const + 88
2  CoreText                       0x2118866a4 (anonymous namespace)::TCGImageData::TCGImageData(TFont const*, unsigned short, TsbixContext const&, CGContext*) + 352
3  CoreText                       0x21188dfa0 DrawGlyphsAtPositions(TFont const*, unsigned short const*, CGPoint const*, unsigned long, CGContext*, CGAffineTransform, CGAffineTransform, bool)::$_9::operator()(CGAffineTransform, CGAffineTransform) const + 124
4  CoreText                       0x2118890c8 DrawGlyphsAtPositions(TFont const*, unsigned short const*, CGPoint const*, unsigned long, CGContext*, CGAffineTransform, CGAffineTransform, bool) + 1252
5  CoreText                       0x211886344 DrawGlyphsWithAdvancesAndTransform(TFont const*, unsigned short const*, CGSize const*, unsigned long, CGPoint, CGContext*, CGAffineTransform, CGAffineTransform, bool) + 340
6  CoreText                       0x211887968 CTFontDrawGlyphsWithAdvancesInternal + 432
7  CoreText                       0x211853978 TRun::DrawGlyphs(CGContext*, CFRange) const + 560
8  CoreText                       0x21186afd0 TLine::DrawGlyphs(CGContext*) const + 184
9  UIFoundation                   0x21817bcc4 -[NSCoreTypesetter _stringDrawingCoreTextEngineWithOriginalString:rect:padding:context:forceClipping:styledTextOptions:attributes:stringDrawingOptions:drawingContext:wantsTextLineFragments:validatedAttributedString:firstNonRenderedCharacterIndex:foundSoftHyphenAtEOL:enginePathUsed:] + 9976
10 UIFoundation                   0x2181f8c74 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 3104
11 UIFoundation                   0x21817c8d4 -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] + 164
12 UIKitCore                      0x23b27cdc8 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 4008
13 UIKitCore                      0x23b27b680 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 684
14 UIKitCore                      0x23b30cda4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 464
15 QuartzCore                     0x21217570c -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 296
16 UIKitCore                      0x23b2815e8 -[_UILabelContentLayer drawInContext:] + 168
17 QuartzCore                     0x212056ca8 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 176
18 QuartzCore                     0x21217c28c invocation function for block in CA::Layer::display_() + 52
19 QuartzCore                     0x212174fc4 -[CALayer _display] + 1540
20 UIKitCore                      0x23b281524 -[_UILabelContentLayer display] + 124
21 QuartzCore                     0x2120d9668 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 548
22 QuartzCore                     0x212107ec8 CA::Transaction::commit() + 608
23 QuartzCore                     0x212108d30 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
24 CoreFoundation                 0x20db096bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
25 CoreFoundation                 0x20db04350 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
26 CoreFoundation                 0x20db048f0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1264
27 CoreFoundation                 0x20db040e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
28 GraphicsServices               0x20fd7d584 GSEventRunModal + 100
29 UIKitCore                      0x23ae64c00 UIApplicationMain + 212
30 MyApp                          0x10258f6a0 main (AppDelegate.swift:21)
31 libdyld.dylib                  0x20d5c2bb4 start + 4
```

Comment: Does this label render attributed text with image attachment by any chance? Is the image in P3 color space? These are wild guesses, but iPhone 7 is the first device to support P3, so it may be as good a starting point as any. Another guess - do you use custom font?

Comment: @Losiowaty So I'm actually unable to replicate the crash, so it's been tough to figure out which label is causing the trouble. Is it possible that `FindColorBitmapForGlyph` is referring to an emoji character that might either be missing or corrupt? There are a lot of emoji in the app... Thank you for the help!